# AS3 How to properly play MovieClips

Tags: actionscript-3, parent

I'm using AS3 on a certain frame, If I call the instance name "guy" of some MovieClip it will start the parent of that MovieClip, and not itself.

```
MovieClip(root).guy.play();
```

If I try to play(); a child of "guy":

```
MovieClip(root).guy.feet1.play();
```

It will say that feet1 is undefined.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I think is the root word

```
MovieClip(guy).play();
MovieClip(guy).feet1.play();
(getChildByName('guy') as MoviClip).play();
(getChildByName('guy') as MoviClip).feet1.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

`root` will goto the parent most display object of the current SWF (if the SWF is loaded in another SWF, it will still surface only to that of the current SWF).

So as a general rule don't use root (although root isn't evil like in AS2, and there are occasional reasons why you might use it).

If `guy` is on the stage, and your actionscript is on the stage, the following should work:

```
guy.play();
guy.feet1.play();
```